# right way of rendering post in reactjs using graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am using reactjs and graphql to make a wordpress theme. I am trying to make something like this [image: layout view]

But I am unable to find a better way to do this by passing post props to three different component which i think is not a good way.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import { getAllPosts } from '../graphql/queries/posts'
import Layout from '../component/Layouts';
import RenderPost from '../component/RenderPost';
import RenderPostExcerpt from '../component/RenderPostExcerpt';
import RenderAllPost from '../component/RenderAllPost';



class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        const posts = this.props.data.posts;
        console.log(posts);
        return (
            <Layout>
                {!posts && <h1>Loading...</h1>}
                {posts && 
                    <div>
                    <RenderPost posts={posts}/>
                    <RenderPostExcerpt posts={posts}/>
                    <RenderAllPost posts={posts}/>
                    </div>
                }
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}

export default graphql(getAllPosts)(Home);
```

I am getting data from wordpress using graphql here Home.js is the parent component.
Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Is `posts` an array of `post` data? `RenderPost` implies a singular post but it looks like you're passing all of them

Comment: yes posts is an array of post. inside Renderpost.js i am slicing first post from rest and in other file i am rendering rest of the post except first one.

Comment: Are you always slicing just the first post? What if you want to render the second or third post?

Comment: i did something like this posts.slice(0, 1).map(post=>()) for first post and posts.slice(1, 5).map(post=>()) for right side of the post where i don't have to pass imageurl  see the image. And i am not sure it is right way or not this is the first time i m making something like this.

Comment: right but... anyways, can you be more clear about what you want? Is your only issue that you're writing `posts={posts}` three times?

Comment: i want to know is this a right way of doing this as i have never seen something like this passing same props to 3 different component.

Comment: or is there any other way like may be using with redux . i am not sure .

Comment: That's completely fine. You could do it differently, but it wouldn't be better. I think what would make a lot more sense in your code is not passing all of the posts to `RenderPost`.. it should take one prop called `post` or even a bunch of post props and do `<RenderPost {...post} />` or something like that

Comment: you could use redux but that's a completely different solution and not related to your question. there's absolutely nothing wrong with passing the same prop to multiple components, it's 100% common thing to do

Comment: okay thank you i will try to pass post instead of posts to every component.